# CF ORM ormExecuteQuery(), What format should dates be?

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion

I have the following method:

```
public function listPublished(){
        var today = createODBCDate(now());
        return ormExecuteQuery("FROM Employment WHERE publishdate <= #today# and expirydate >= #today# ORDER BY tstamp desc");
}
```

When I run it I am getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '{' [FROM EmploymentFindSonographer WHERE publishdate <= {d '2012-10-15'} and expirydate >= {d '2012-10-15'} ORDER BY tstamp desc]
```

My guess is that HQL requires the format in something other than ODBC date?  I also tried passing in a standard CF Date but same error.

Can anyone tell me what format my dates should be in when passing HQL into ormExecuteQuery?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpe version:

```
ormExecuteQuery("FROM Employment WHERE publishdate <= :today and expirydate >= :today ORDER BY tstamp desc", {today = Now()});
```

Possible problem is that Now() outputs seconds which could give you unexpected results if publishDate and expiryDate keep date+time.

So, possibly more accurate way is this:

```
ormExecuteQuery("FROM Employment WHERE publishdate <= :today and expirydate >= :today ORDER BY tstamp desc", {today = DateFormat(Now(), 'yyyy-mm-dd')});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DateFormat(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```